# How do I configure FluentNHibernate to not overwrite an existing SQLite db file?

Tags: nhibernate, sqlite, fluent-nhibernate

Here is my configuration:

```
this.factory = Fluently.Configure().
    Database(SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.UsingFile("foo.db").
        ShowSql()).
    Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Bar>()).
    ExposeConfiguration(BuildSchema).
    BuildSessionFactory();
```

BuildSchema looks like this:

```
private static void BuildSchema(Configuration config)
{
    new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
}
```

Luckily this works great and creates a file named foo.db to which I can read and write. Unluckily, every time i run this code, foo.db is overwritten. How can I configure (Fluent)NHibernate to create the file only if it doesn't already exist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put an if statement in your BuildSchema?

```
if (!File.Exists("foo.db"))
  new SchemaExport(config).Create(false, true);
```