# fluent nhibernate data is not persisting

Tags: c#, hibernate, fluent-nhibernate

Here is the helper;

```
public class NHibernateHelper
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        { 
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
            {
                InitSessionFactory();
                return _sessionFactory;
            }
        }

    private static void InitSessionFactory()
    {
        _sessionFactory =
            Fluently.Configure().Database(
                MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
                    "ConnectionString").ShowSql).
                Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Category>()).ExposeConfiguration(
                    cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg).Create(true, true)).BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

Below code is the code to store data:

```
using(var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
{
    using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    { 
        session.Save(category);
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

My problem is when i run this code and i refresh database, i see data is going through.

When i restart the application, data is gone.

How can i persist the data to db?

Comment: does export schema recreates database or just updates if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as if you are constantly re-creating the database file:

`SchemaExport(cfg).Create(`

As asked and solved here:

[How do I configure FluentNHibernate to not overwrite an existing SQLite db file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253474/how-do-i-configure-fluentnhibernate-to-not-overwrite-an-existing-sqlite-db-file)

So it is persisting within an app session, but once you restart the app (or more accurately call `SchemaExport` again) the database file is re-created.

Comment: @DarthVader Fair enough, I didn't pay attention to your rep.